# Looping through multiple worksheets and tables to do a multi-criteria sort

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

Trying to create a loop that goes through multiple worksheets, selects the table and sorts it based on multiple criteria. Each worksheet only has one table, and this is what I've come up with so far.

```
    Sub sorter()
'
' sorter Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+F
'

Dim varTblSortName As Variant
varTblSortName = ActiveSheet.Name
Dim Client As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range



For Each Client In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
'This tests to make sure the code is only run on Client_ sheets
    If InStr(1, Client.Name, "Client_", vbTextCompare) Then
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)


     Worksheets(Client.Name).Activate
        'ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.Select

            'Range(, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Client_Jamie").ListObjects("Client_Jamie").Sort. _

               ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields.Clear
            ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort. _
                SortFields.Add Key:=Range("varTblSortName[Asset Class]"), SortOn:= _
                xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort. _
                SortFields.Add Key:=Range("varTblSortName[Sector]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects("varTblSortName").Sort. _
                SortFields.Add Key:=Range("varTblSortName[Ticker]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects("varTblSortName").Sort
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
            End If
        Next Client
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there anything that doesn't work as intended? If not then I recommend CodeReview instead.

Comment: I meant to mention this in the post, but i think the issue I'm having is excel not accepting varTblSortName as the range in the =Range part. Each table is the same name as the active sheet. Ex a worksheet titled "Countries" has a table within it called "Countries".

Answer (score 0):

I've extended the use of With/End With and broken your string variables out of the quoted strings.

```
Sub sorter()
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+F
    Dim varTblSortName As Variant
    Dim Client As Worksheet

    For Each Client In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With Client
            If CBool(InStr(1, .Name, "Client_", vbTextCompare)) Then
                varTblSortName = .Name
                With .ListObjects(varTblSortName)
                    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
                    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(varTblSortName & "[Asset Class]"), SortOn:= _
                        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(varTblSortName & "[Sector]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(varTblSortName & "[Ticker]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    With .Sort
                        .Header = xlYes
                        .MatchCase = False
                        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                        .Apply
                    End With
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next Client
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly! still learning vba, so what is the purpose of the Cbool line/can you explain it?

Comment: It generally isn't necessary as *False* is considered to be *0* and anything that is not *False* is *True*. Using `CBool` is really just my coding style and tells me that the `InStr` is being evaluated as boolean.